# Strange Behavior when saving customer with deletedatabaserecord=1

Tags: acumatica

This issue brothers me for a long time.

I have two environments. 1 for development, 1 for production.
I did the same steps as below:

1, Create a new customer named "TESTID"

2, Delete the "TESTID" after creation immediately. At this time, it would be marked deleteddatabaserecord =1 in BAccount table.

Now, here comes huge different. If I recreated the "TESTID" in my development environment, the system allows and just update the deleteddatabaserecord to 0 and other fields updated according to new input. However, the production environment won't allow to created the customer "TESTID", says "Can not insert duplicated line into object "dbo.BAccount" with unique index. The duplicated key is (2,TESTID)"

This issue also happens to other entities, such as Stock Item. So is there a switch or specific setting?I would be really appreciated if somebody could give me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you can't insert entity into the table because of unique index constraint. And you don't have such error in another environment. I'd started investigating from checking if indexes are the same for dbo.BAccount table in either of the environments.

Comment: Thank you. But the question is in the development environment, it is not an "Insert" action, it is an "update". The logic is different,but the steps are the same. That is something I don't understand. Well, this question is specifically relating to an ERP system called Acumatica, can you reproduce the same steps in it?

Comment: Sorry, tried in 19.110.0013 not repeated. I can remove and recreate the customer with same ID using Customers screen.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I also can remove and recreate the customer with same ID on my laptop in whatever versions. But the same version on the cloud server will meet errors. Really weird.